# Remove message, Framework7

Tags: javascript, css, html-framework-7

I can't seem to remove just one message using the JS framework, Framework7. There is a "myMessages.removeMessage(message);" where message is "HTMLElement or string (with CSS Selector) of message element to remove.". But I cant get this to work on just 1 message. Either all gets removed or none. Ive inspected the elements and they all seem to be the same (see screenshot). Removing all can be done with e.g.

```
    myMessages.removeMessage(".message-first");
```

Adding e.g. ".message-received" removes all received messages and so on. Cant find anything that separates between the very last message and all others.

Anyone that has any idea how to remove the last message (or a specific message) with Framework7?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dom library from Framework7 ([doc](http://framework7.io/docs/dom.html)), to delete the last element who matched with `".message-first"`, simply do a `$$.find()`, take last item and delete it with `.delete()`.

Comment: thanks. However, Id very much prefer to use the already built way to do it, myMessages.removeMessage(message), I just want to know how that works. If that is broken then Ill try some other way.

Comment: Ive not been able to get any response from my issue in the corresponding github so Ive tried to go your route, however, without any "luck". I cant see any ".delete()" as per your suggestion but I assume you mean ".remove()". However, using that, i.e. " $$('.message-first').remove();" ALL messages get removed. How do I go about using ".find()" to get the last message? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Pasting it here below for future reference.
1) var info = $$('.messages').find('.message-first');
2) info[info.length-1].remove();